# Converting C-String into an int Array

Tags: c++

So for my programming assignment I have to

Process data from an input file and do some stuff to it.

Here's the parameters.

An instructor has a class of no more than 40 students each of whom takes 6 tests. For
each student in the class, there is one line in the input file. The line contains the student's first
name (no more than 10 characters), last name (no more than 12 characters), ID# (a string of 6 characters) and 6 integer test scores.
Input text file should be named
student_input.dat

Also note that amount of blank spaces between
names, ID, and grades
can be arbitrary, i.e., any number. There will be at least one space though.
There might be a space between the last grade and the invisible symbol that signifies the end of the line ‘/n’.
Total amount of characters for each line will not exceed 256, including the end of
the line symbol.

Also we cannot use anything involving strings, so that pretty much limits me to using only c strings.

My questions is I am currently stuck on trying to convert an extracted string of char which are the grades into an int array so I can do maths to them.

Here is my current code.

```
int main()
{
    char * lastName;
    char * firstName;
    char * idNumber;
    char * testScores;
    char rawData[256] = "";
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("student_input.dat");

    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "Program terminated. Input file did not open." << endl;
        fin.close();
        return 1;
    }

    if(fin)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < 41; i++)
        {
            fin.getline(rawData, 256, '\n');
            lastName = strtok(rawData, " ");
            cout << lastName;
            firstName = strtok(NULL, " ");
            cout << firstName;
            idNumber = strtok(NULL, " ");
            cout << idNumber << "  ";
            for( int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                testScores = strtok(NULL, " ");
                cout << testScores << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing each character of CString in a for loop and converting them to int with atoi() so you can save them into an int array?

Comment: I'm only in my second semester of coding and the instructor hasn't explained atoi() and I've never heard of it before? 

Can you elaborate on how to use atoi()?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: Sure: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi. If your a student you should know that the most important thing to know is where it is written down.

Comment: @TienNguyen A good way to learn about something that you don't know about is google or look through your textbooks. 99~95% of the time you will find the answer that you are looking for by searching on google.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I've completed my assignment 4 days early because I couldn't sleep last night because my mind was running over my code constantly trying to figure out what was wrong and how to work it. 

Anyhow I'm going to post it up on my original question just for constructive criticism. You know just so I know how to more efficiently do things later on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you possibly are having two specific issues:

1. How to extract the specific data values from a string?
2. How to convert a string containing numerical characters into a number?

I am giving you two solutions (not posting actual code as it is a (possibly) school assignment).

Solution 1:

```
1. Let input be a string or array of characters
2. Read the entire line into input
3. Set index = 0
4. while (index is not beyond the end of input)
    4.1. Set start = (first non-whitespace character in input starting from index)
    4.2. Set end = (first whitespace character / end of line character / end of file in input starting from start)
    4.3. Set substring = (string containing the characters in input from indices start to end-1, both end inclusive)
    4.4. Save substring (into an array or whatever).
    4.5. Set index = end
5. end-while
```

This way, you have got all whitespace separated substrings as different strings. Process them as you like (i.e., first substring is the first name, second is the last name and so on)...

Once you have located your strings that contain the grades, either use atoi from the comments to your question or write a function that converts a string containing a single number into an integer.

Solution 2:

```
1. Declare three string (or array of chars) variables firstname, lastname and id
2. Declare six integers naming grade1 to grade6
3. Use the >> operator of ifstream to read into the values sequentially, that is, read to firstname, lastname, id, grade1,...grade6
```

The >> operator is supposed to take care of the string or integer matters, and you don't have the worry about the number of spaces either.

If you want to avoid atoi, which I would not recommend to avoid, then here is a simple algorithm to convert a collection of digits to a number:

```
1. Let input = array of characters / string containing only numerical letters.
2. Set index = 0
3. Set sum = 0
4. While index is not beyond the last index at input
    4.1. Set c = the character at index
    4.2. Set value = ASCII value of c
    4.3. Set sum = sum * 10 + value;
    4.4. Increase index by 1
5. End-while
```

Hope this helps :)